# Is it possible to tell which Oracle cluster node was called?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting different `sysdate` results depending on the node. But how to figure out which are the problematic nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are able to connect via sqlplus or another tool and assuming you are using TNS names.....

If the assumptions above are correct your TNS names will look somthing like the below

```
(DESCRIPTION=
  (ADDRESS_LIST=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales1-server)(PORT=1521))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=sales2-server)(PORT=1521)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.example.com)))
```

You can then simply remove all nodes except 1 (backing up file first of course) then connect to via SQLPULS or your tool of choice and do..

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

Rinse and repeat for each of the nodes in the TNSNames original file, until you find which are the problematic nodes, although I am unsure of any reason that different nodes would give a different sysdate.

Answer (score 0):

This query tells you which node your session is using:

```
select * from v$instance;
```

You can use the undocumented `GV$` table function to run a query against all RAC instances to find out which ones have a bad clock. The function is a bit tricky because the cursor gets parsed on your instance but executed on all the instances. It's not always clear exactly where the code is running, and you may have to create a PL/SQL function to ensure that the code is truly executing on the remote instance.

```
create or replace function get_sysdate return date is
begin
    return sysdate;
end;
/

select * from
table(gv$(cursor(
    select instance_name, get_sysdate from v$instance
)));
```

Unfortunately I am not able to fully test the above code since I don't have access to change the time on any RAC clusters. But I've used similar code in the past.